# Get latest release version number for chrome browser

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I am trying to figure out a rather stable way to programmatically determine the latest release version number of the chrome browser.

It doesn't have to be failproof as it's only a nice-to-have-feature I can blend out whenever the result looks "suspicious".

- There seems to be no API (is there?).
- I dont want to rely on third parties handling that stuff manually.
- I dont want to parse any website output.

So I ended up fetching git files.

My first approach was to fetch this file:

```
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/chrome/VERSION?format=TEXT
```

Which gives the latest version number.
From there on the solution is just a preg_match_all away ...
Unfortunately its not the latest release version but the latest dev version.

There seems to be no "release" branch nor a "release" tag or something else I can think of neither.

You might answer "why?"... I know about feature detection, I know browser sniffing can be fooled and I am aware of the fact that (every) browser will notify their users when it's time to update. Still makes sense in my case. On the other hand its solely for display purposes. Nothing is going to depend on it later on – promise :-)

Any – even the faintest – ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: It really doesn't make sense what you want to do. Chrome keeps itself automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks, for your Answer. That is why I wrote the paragraph 'You might answer "why?"'. Trust me it does make sense in this case. It doesn't make sense on its own – I agree. But I am printing out the latest release numbers for a couple of browsers (which too makes sense in my case). For the sake of consistency I want to print out the latest version for chrome too.
But thank you anyway for trying to save me some time – really appreciate that Charlotte!

Comment: Well, then you need to parse HTML, I don't see any other way.

Comment: Thanks. I already did something like pushing a HEAD Request and parsing the Location Header of the response for a redirected Download-Link for Firefox and using a regex to filter out the version number inside that link. Works quite well and could work out quite stable. I was hoping someone comes around with an equally adventurous solution for chrome. I am hoping solutions like that stay stable longer. A Website is changed quite frequently. A build process stays that way for a longer time. I keep waiting and hoping.

Comment: I couldn't imagine websites like [these](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) do that manually all the time...

Comment: If you're on debian based linux, you could install and update your chrome once a day, and somehow parse the installation log and save it.

Comment: @peixotorms that sounds like one of these solutions I was hoping to find here! Big thanks! This will be my last resort, as I would like to be able to keep it kinda portable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Chrome team uses the [OmahaProxy](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/) dashboard to keep track of current versions in stable/beta/dev/canary. If you can scrape that you can get whatever version number you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even easier than previous solutions, but I am a little suspicious that the "view" (meaning the html structure) of said document might change more often than the data/structure from @peixotorms answer.
+ way easier
- more 'fragile'

Comment: At the bottom of that page (you may have to scroll down), there's links to get the data as raw CSV or JSON

Comment: OmahaProxy has been deprecated and is no longer usable for this purpose (September 2023).

Answer (score 8):

I've found the following endpoints from OmahaProxy that give the latest stable versions of the respective OS.

- Windows: https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/win
- Linux: https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/linux
- Mac: https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/mac

Comment: OmahaProxy has been deprecated and is no longer usable for this purpose (September 2023).

Answer (score 5):

Feel free to use my online service vergrabber to get latest versions of different kind of software in json format.
It's available at http://vergrabber.kingu.pl/vergrabber.json

Comment: Cool Thanks @twk! How did you technically manage the chrome part?
Should you need the other browsers too: feel free to try my first attempt for an api for browser versions: https://browserapi.nachvorne.de By far not perfect and actually even fetches some browser versions (some only fallback) by crawling wikipedia until I come across a better idea but might work partly. Gotta work on sanitizing the fetched Version numbers too as you can determine by looking at the output data.

Comment: I write a module for every app to scrap version info directly from their official website. This is the most accurate I think, because wikipedia is updated manualy as far as I know.

Comment: For Chrome, I use json from the page mentioned above by @DavidBokan.

Comment: I do a mixture of both. The official website is updated the fastest, but website's markup change quite often so this fails from time to time. On the other hand wikipedia is a bit outdated (usually a few hours) but more stable. I'd prefer git or dashboards or the like as a source. Rather fail proof and even faster than the official websites.

Comment: Website's markup doesn't change that often. I need to update my scrapping scripts from time to time, maybe once a month for a 20 apps.

Comment: This API has not been updated since 2021

Answer (score 5):

The ChromiumDash also makes the data available via an API. You can use that to fetch the latest tag for a platform and a channel.

Eg: https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/fetch_releases?channel=Stable&platform=Windows&num=1

Returns

```
[
  {
    "channel": "Stable", 
    "chromium_main_branch_position": 950365, 
    "hashes": {
      "angle": "343b7bb57268e1cb47da26fcb0ed40fe47e8ff5d", 
      "chromium": "cab11adacc41ee856c79e669c2fd38d8864e52c4", 
      "dawn": "1b1b658d365591b6a8d4bfb0c3524832c89afc99", 
      "devtools": "b6f648d8921ea8be8f2b32c2061fec7503b56610", 
      "pdfium": "27cabf3dae38d0634a53316da0ad069bf0413495", 
      "skia": "a6986cd7224f104044fd5bc29cb5f80796d76f5a", 
      "v8": "db77a493a5595b835655b243202ac0c2fb1898a6", 
      "webrtc": "a6b138d6b4ef3a5b2c87f899b67f3b5c8dd3c002"
    }, 
    "milestone": 98, 
    "platform": "Windows", 
    "previous_version": "98.0.4758.81", 
    "time": 1643754840000, 
    "version": "98.0.4758.82"
  }
]
```

Comment: Good find. Two things worth noting however: there's an "Extended" channel which you may want vs the "Stable" channel. And Google seems to do 50/50 releases and item 0 may be actually older than item 1 in the JSON (e.g. right now where "120.0.6099.72" is #0 and "120.0.6099.109" is #1). See https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/releases?platform=Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you're on debian based linux, you could install and update your chrome once a day, and somehow parse the version number, but this is not realtime.

For example:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Which will give a log like this:

```
(Reading database ... 113338 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (48.0.2564.97-1) over (47.0.2526.111-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (48.0.2564.97-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
```

Then just parse it.

Comment: That's a badass answer! Genious. Still hoping for something portable which doesn't include the need to have install-privileges.

Comment: You could set a cron job once a day and let it update a database, write to a text file or something. I don't think there's any other way that doing this without installing or checking manually.

Comment: Absolutely doesn't have to be realtime. I am playing around with downloading that file and reading contents (tar xzpvf). We'll see where I get from there.

Comment: un-tar that file results in a control.tar.gz being created. Inside that one we have a file named 'control'. Row 2 in that said file says "Version: 48.0.2564.97-1". No need to install the package. Case closed! Thanks so much! Saved my day.

Comment: that's even better, no need to install :)