# Is there a way to fetch the most recent version number of the major browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari

I would like to programatically have access to the latest *version numbers* of the major browsers. I looked at a few scripts like [outdated-browser.js](https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser) but it seems to do a live check for modern functions instead of strict version numbers (aside from IE) (not to mention I'd like to do this server-side).

Ideally I'd like a JSON list like:

```
{
  "Browsers": {
    "Chrome":  "68.0.3440.106",
    "Firefox": "61.0.2",
    "Safari":  "11.1.2"
  }
}
```

Of course, that's ideal - but if there's even a way to ping Google for the most recent version of Chrome, that would be sufficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114642/get-latest-release-version-number-for-chrome-browser

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm not sure why that solution didn't come up in my SO searches - but I'll mark it as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get latest release version number for chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114642/get-latest-release-version-number-for-chrome-browser)