# How to get the list of chrome versions

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I am writing some react code and I need to know the last 3 versions of chrome.
Is there an api to get all chrome versions, or to get the last 3 versions of chrome?

Comment: What is meant by "last 3 versions" — [semver](https://semver.org/) major?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get latest release version number for chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114642/get-latest-release-version-number-for-chrome-browser)

Comment: I want to programatically get the last 3 versions, not just the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try  "[omahaproxy](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)", you can use fetch or axios with this url : 'https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/history.json'